# Prove that $\pi: G\to G/H$ is a group homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. I want to prove that $$\pi: G\to G/H$$
defined as $\pi(g)=gH$ is a group homomorphism, i.e. $$(gg')H=(gH)(g'H),$$
for all $g,g'\in G$.

- For $(gg')H\subset (gH)(g'H) :$ Let $k\in (gg')H$. Then there is $h\in H$ s.t. $$k=gg'h=g1_Hg'h\in (gH)(g'H).$$
- For the converse, let $k\in (gH)(g'H)$. Then, there is $h,h'$ s.t. $$k=ghg'h'.$$
  Now, how can I get $k\in (gg')H$ ? I guess I have to use the fact that $H$ is normal, but I don't really see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of equivalent definitions for a normal subgroup.
For example, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for every $g\in G$ and $h\in H$.

Using this fact, $$k=ghg'h'=gg'[(g')^{-1}hg']h'$$
By using the definition I stated, $(g')^{-1}hg'\in H$, so $[(g')^{-1}hg']h'\in H$.
Hence we have $k\in gg'H.$

Answer (score 0):

$Hg' = g'H$ implies that there is an $h^\dagger\in H$ such that $hg' = g'h^\dagger$. Now we have $k = gg'h^\dagger h'$, and you're finished.